# Complete list of prerequisites to study "An Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds" by Lee.

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, soft-question, riemannian-geometry, book-recommendation

I am currently very confused about the "topological" prerequisites of Lee's Riemannian Geometry (RG) book, [*An Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-91755-9). I have heard that this is a "truly introductory" text for beginners in RG. But as for prerequisites, in his preface Lee states that his other two books on Topological and Smooth Manifolds are a sufficient preparation for his RG text. But from several online forums I've come to the realizations that this would be an "overkill" just for studying RG (e.g., one need *not* study *all* of his Topological Manifolds text to study *most* of his Smooth Manifolds text!). So, in general, his preface is confusing to me when discussing prerequisites.

I'm confident with my analysis background (inverse/implicit function theorem, etc.) As for the differential geometry stuff, I'm thinking about going over doCarmo's [*Curves & Surfaces*](https://a.co/d/flsH2xY) text. I'm a beginner in DG and I prefer E. Kreyszig's [*Differential Geometry*](https://a.co/d/c9l8qKb) as it introduces tensors early on (something I'm highly interested in learning about). I'm also aware of another "standard" text on [RG by doCarmo](https://a.co/d/gO2hwRf) as well. So, here's what I need guidance on:

- Which of the books among Lee and doCarmo on RG is preferable if one wants to get a decent exposure to RG so that they can pursue research in related areas?
- How much topology does one need to know in order to tackle the texts by Lee and/or doCarmo on RG?
- For differential geometry, is Kreyszig's DG book sufficient to prepare for Lee and/or doCarmo's RG text(s)? Or is it preferable to study do Carmo's DG before tackling RG?

My ultimate goal is (broadly) mathematical physics, in particular, Relativity and Quantum Gravity. Moreover, I consider myself *more* of a "math"-person and so would *not* prefer texts that **ruin** mathematical rigor.